# Using boost condition variable timed_wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread, condition-variable

I want to implement the following case:

- A worker thread that is continuously running unless interrupted by calling boost::thread::interrupt
- The thread must pause for 100 ms at the end of each block, but must immediately wake up and continue if notified by another thread to do so

  ```
  WorkerThread()
  {
      while(true)
     {
        ...
        ...
        ... //done with a block of work

        //Pause for 100 ms unless notified by another 
       //thread to wake up and continue immediately
    }
  }
  ```

**Question:** Can I use boost::condition_variable::timed_wait in the following way to get the following scenario working?

```
boost::condition_variable cond;

WorkerThread()
{
    while(true)
    {
       ...
       ...
       ... //done with a block of work


       boost::mutex mut;
       boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut); // this lock will always be 
                                                   //acquired  since no one else 
                                                   //locks *mut*
       cond.timed_wait( lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100) );
    }
}

OtherThread()
{
   //need to make the worker thread immediately wake up
   cond.notify_one();
}
```

Would this work? If not, how do I achieve the scenario above?

Comment: Looks okay. However, you should call [boost::condition_variable::timed_wait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable.timed_wait) in a loop due to spurious wake-ups.